# Improving a LIKE clause through static clause elements

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I am curious if using a `LIKE` clause can be optimized by using static clause elements.

Is this query

```
(SELECT * FROM n where n.name = 'x' AND n.body LIKE '%x%';)
```

faster than this one

```
(SELECT * FROM n WHERE n.body LIKE '%x%';)
```

I use a mysql.

Comment: You need to add more information to your question.  For example, what datatype are 'name' and 'body'?

Comment: Have you considered testing this yourself?

Comment: The question I was asking was, is it faster to narrow a LIKE search with a static WHERE clause. Than to just perform a LIKE search.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `EXPLAIN` to know which query is faster.

As a general concept it is better to have static queries than `LIKE` queries. So it gets faster if you add some.

But only if it actually reduces the rows for the `LIKE` and the static query uses and index.

The principle is that a `LIKE` style query (together with other queries that have to scan through the content of the field) is expensive. (see the `cost` column in the `EXPLAIN`)
So, if you reduce the amount of rows that need to be treated for a `LIKE` the query gets faster.

What exactly makes what query fast under what circumstances is hard to answer generally. You should ask precise questions to them including a description of your concrete situation (DBMS, table model, indexes, amount of data, result of an `EXPLAIN` call, etc.) to get working answers.

Comment: And only if an index can be used for the static querty.

Comment: Thank you I will use the EXPLAIN keyword and see which is faster.

Answer (score 2):

It could be faster if you have an index on `n.name`.  I believe that MySQL always uses indexes when available on a column.  If only a few rows have `n.name = 'x'`, then the engine will select those rows and perform the `like` operation only on them.

Because `like` has wildcards on both sides, it cannot take advantage of an index.

If there are no indexes, then the additional comparison would add a very, very small amount of overhead into the query, although it might also short-circuit the `like`.  It is unclear which would be the dominant factor, but reading the data from disk might dominate the query anyway.